# Receiving HTTP 404 when validating a Double property with min constraint in Grails

Tags: validation, grails, constraints, double

For a simple class like,

```
class Person {

    String Name

    Double incomeFromWork = new Double(0.0)

    static constraints = {
        incomeFromWork(min:0d)
    }
}
```

However on the GSP page I get an "HTTP ERROR: 404" error when I enter alphabets for `incomeFromWork` value. What constraints should I use to accept a valid `Double` value as an income?

Thanks,
BT

Answer (score 2):

Your constraints don't have any problems; they will correctly validate a `Double` property.

It's likely that your problem is in your controller. You're probably either redirecting to an undefined action or rendering a view that doesn't exist.

*As an aside, you should probably rename `Name` to `name` to meet standard member naming conventions.*